# Pass quoted arguments to shell script and maintain quoting

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I'm attempting to re-use parameters sent to my script as parameters for a command I execute *within* my script. See example below where I execute `mailx`.

**bash**

```
$./myscript.sh "My quoted Argument"
```

**myscript.sh**

```
mailx -s $1
```

This ends up being executed as: `mailx -s My Quoted Argument`.

---

- I tried `"$1"`, but my quotes are thrown away. **(Incorrect statement, read answer below)**
- I tried `""$1""` but my quotes are thrown away.
- I tried to do `'$1'` but that's strong quoting so $1 never gets interpreted.
- I realize I can do `$@`, but that gives me every param.
- .... you get the picture

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`mailx -s "$1"` correctly passes the value of `$1` to `mailx` as-is, embedded spaces and all.

In the case at hand, this means that `My Quoted Argument` is passed as a *single*, literal argument to `mailx`, which is probably your intent.

In a shell command line, quotes around string literals are *syntactic* elements *demarcating argument boundaries* that are *removed* by the shell in the process of parsing the command line (a process called [quote removal](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/quoting)).

If you really wanted to pass *embedded* double-quotes (which would be unusual), you have 2 options:

- either: embed the quotes on invocation `./myscript.sh "\"My quoted Argument\""`
- or: embed the quotes inside `myscript.sh`: `mailx -s "\"$1\""`

Comment: Thanks @mklement0. Somehow in my testing, I must have overlooked quoting the argument in my script when passing it to `mailx`.

Answer (score -1):

Can you try passing the argument like this

```
$./myscript.sh \"My quoted Argument\"?
```

Comment: I would like to be able to pass arguments as I would to any normal command without having to understand the inner workings of that command. I.e. I do not want to modify how I pass parameters because of a shortcoming of the scripts design.

Answer (score -1):

You may just put escaped quotes around `$1` in your script

```
mailx -s \"$1\"
```